# Graph of a negative exponential function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I know that $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R \\ \quad\; x \to f(x)$ with $f(x)=a^x, a \in \Bbb R$ is defined for $0<a\not=1$ and that for $a < 0$ there is no solution in $\Bbb R$.

My  question is, is there a well defined solution in $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb C \\ \quad\; x \to f(x)$ with $f(x)=a^x, a \in \Bbb R$ and $a < 0 \land a \not= -1$? Also can $a=-1$ in this case?

**EDIT:**

I also want to know if there is some way to plot the graph of a funciton like that.

Comment: I would say:       $(-1)^x = \left(e^{i \pi}\right)^x = e^{i \pi x} = \cos(\pi x) + i \sin(\pi x)$

Comment: $(-3)^x=-27 \iff x=3$

Answer (score 1):

Complex exponentiation $a^x$ is **always** defined for all $a,x\in\mathbb{C}$. *a* can be **any** real or complex number and $f(x)$ will always be defined. ($0^0=1$.)