# Is $(-1)^x=(e^{\pi i})^x$

Tags: complex-numbers

In one of my questions here on mathematics about [Graph of a negative exponential function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1880005/graph-of-a-negative-exponential-function) One of the comments was that I could indeed have $(-1)^x$ since $(-1)^x = (e^{i\pi})^x = \cos(\pi x) + i\sin(\pi x)$. What I want to know is, is this identity $(-1)^x=(e^{\pi i})^x$ true? If yes, is there a proof for that?

Comment: $-1=\cos(\pi)+i\sin(\pi)=e^{i\pi}$.

Comment: True because $e^{i\pi}=-1$

Comment: Recall Euler's Identity-https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_identity ....$e^{i\pi}=-1$

Comment: This is indeed true, but before you make a step further, let me point out that $(a^b)^c=a^{bc}$ is not valid anymore in the world of complex numbers, so trying to apply it can lead to some absurds.

Comment: @Wojowu so $(a^b)^c \not= a^{bc}$? Could you give me any example for why of that?

Comment: What about $(e^{-i\pi})^{1/2}$?

Comment: @Carlos Afonso : $(-1)^x$ is not always defined - e.g. $(-1)^\frac{1}{3}$ isn't unique. Therefore $(e^{i\pi})^x$ is an extension of $(-1)^x$, not an identity.

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above (and possibly comments) should give an explanation why. (In particular, [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) might be useful.) You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote whether to reopen it or leave it closed. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Comment: Just to understand: are you aware that the presently accepted answer is deeply misleading and cannot be considered as satisfying?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's true.
First of all $(A)^x=(B)^x$ implies that the equality is true regardless the value of $x$ if $A=B$ .

You had just to prove that $e^{\pi i} = -1$ and it's the Euler's identity.
She is bas on the definition of the exponential :

$e^{i x } = cos(x) + i sin(x)$

$cos(\pi) = -1$

and

$sin(\pi) = 0$

so $-1+i*0= -1 = e^{\pi i}$

Comment: "First of all $(A)^x=(B)^x$ implies that the equality is true regardless the value of $x$ if $A=B$" True, but only if there exists a canonical function $\varphi:z\mapsto z^x$... and this is where the trouble begins, which invalidates your answer.

Comment: This is the first time I am seeing a post with $-2$ score as an accepted answer....

Answer (score 1):

There’s a problem, because you haven’t said what “$(-1)^x$” *means*.

Any definition of $a^b$ when $b$ is not an integer and $a$ is not positive real must pass through evaluation of $\log a$, and this is not a single-valued function unless $a$ is positive.

Even the “formula” $\log(e^x)$ must be considered to be ambiguous when $x$ is not real, even though it must be admitted that one particular evaluation of this expression is obvious.

**EDIT**:

To give an idea of how wrong your intended equation is, look at
\begin{align}
e^{-i\pi}&=-1=e^{i\pi}\\
\left(e^{-i\pi}\right)^{1/2}&=\left(e^{i\pi}\right)^{1/2}\quad\text{(ill-defined exponentiation)}\\
e^{-i\pi/2}&=e^{i\pi/2}\quad\text{(by your equation)}\\
-i&=i
\end{align}
It goes wrong at two places: in line 2, because the exponent is not an integer *and* the base is not positive; and in line 3, because your equation is not valid.

Comment: Sorry for ambiguity. $x \in \Bbb R$ and $(-1)^x \in \Bbb C$

Comment: That’s mathematical ambiguity I’m talking about, not a stylistic or linguistic ambiguity. To be completely clear, I’ll add something to my answer.